# Jmeter - Execute sampler once per test

Tags: java, jmeter, threadgroup

I have below test plan in my jmeter

```
|Test Plan
|-Thread Group
|--HTTP Request 1
|--HTTP Request 2
|--HTTP Request 3
```

In Thread Group I have setted:

- Number of Threads - 5
- Ramp-Up Period (in seconds) - 0
- Loop Count -1

When I run my test Jmeter executes each request five times. I'm looking for way how to execute each sampler only once in whole test run, I know I can achive it by setting Number of Threads to 1, but in that case execution of test will be very slow, so I would like to do this in parallel way.

Any ideas how can I do it ? I know I can't use Only Once Controller because each request is also executed by each thread.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is use [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller)  as the parent of each request

> Throughput Controller allows the user to control how often it is executed.

Choose `Total executions` with Throughput  value `1`

> Total executions
>   causes the controller to stop executing after a certain number of executions have occurred.

It will execute only once each request as you needed

Answer (score 0):

You don't need more than 1 thread, you can add JMeter plugin [bzm - Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md)

Add it as the parent of the three request and it will execute it in parallel

[image]

Comment: @DimtriT Why downvoting ? it's a working solution for parallel requests

Comment: Yes, your answer was helpful. But I will wait a little bit more time, maybe someone will provide solution as I described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52149578/jmeter-execute-sampler-once-per-test?noredirect=1#comment91252395_52150188

Comment: @KamilW. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52149578/jmeter-execute-sampler-once-per-test/52161333#52161333

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your requests under the [Switch Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/selection-statements-in-jmeter-made-easy)
2. Use [`${__threadNum}`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function  as the "Switch Value"

Scenario outline:

[image: JMeter Switch Controller]

Comment: As I checked in this approach number of threads must match number of requests. In case when I will have a lot of requests my pc can be overloaded. It could be wonderful if we find a solution where we have e.g 5 threads and when one thread finish one request it moves to another request, until all request will be finished. Any ideas ? :)

Comment: Not necessarily, the number of threads can be lower, in this case some requests will be  executed sequentially

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller) this controller runs once per testrun. "*The Once Only Controller will now execute always during the first iteration of any looping parent controller*"

Comment: I put my requests under Once Only Controller which is under Loop Controller and unfortonetly each request is executed once per each declared thread.

Comment: Try a simple if controller with the statement "${__threadNum}" == "1" put your requests under it.