# Jmeter connections - confusion

Tags: jmeter

I have a test with Ultimate thread group (for 750 users) that has three links in it. My simple query is when i start the test how are the virtual users hitting those links? Is it like 750 user per link (that makes 750x3=2250 users) or 750 usres distributed across those links? Appreciate you help.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Each user/thread is executing the **same flow** in Thread group (unless you use [special controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52149578/jmeter-execute-sampler-once-per-test/52161333#52161333) to avoid it)

In your flow there are 3 requests so it'll execute 750x3=2250 **requests**.